# Macros Internet handling

Tags: vba

Im newly working on the macros to handling internet page automatically and im confused on how to make it work.

We have a page and there are few click which will navigate to another page whether we will enter the values manually and submit the ticket. Im working to automate this by creating the macros.

Basically once the page is opened, We need to scroll on the text, and it will pop up like a screen for the option and from the option we need to click to navigate to next page. here the confusion is im using getelementbyid or getelementbyclassname or getelementbytagname but none of the options are working.

Can any one help to find the correct id/classname/tag

```
Sub Create_Change_ITMS()
Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim ele As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
URL = "URL"
IE.Navigate URL
Sleep 10000
'' get element code here
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML URL

```
<div class="item EP lvl1 " style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; border-top-color: currentColor; border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-top-width: medium;border-bottom-width: medium; border-top-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; background-color: rgb(106, 184, 233);" artype="NavBarItem" arid="app1592" arwindowid="0" navmode="1" lvl="1">
```

New Change

Comment: What are you calling this from, Excel? Word?

Comment: Your code is literally just opening IE and navigating to a page - where have you tried to get the element you've described in the code? We need a relevant example of the code you're actually using.